# How draw a stacked column chart with type datetime

Tags: highcharts

Whats the reason for the following chart don't render dates on the xAxis:

http://jsfiddle.net/NwkAr/

This are the settings:

```
{
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Stacked column chart'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: [10000, 20000, 30000, 40000],
    type: 'datetime'
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Total fruit consumption'
    },
    stackLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      style: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
      }
    }
  },
  legend: {
    align: 'right',
    x: -70,
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    y: 20,
    floating: true,
    backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColorSolid) || 'white',
    borderColor: '#CCC',
    borderWidth: 1,
    shadow: false
  },
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function () {
      return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' + this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' + 'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      stacking: 'normal',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
  }, {
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
  }, {
    name: 'Joe',
    data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove categories, you can't use categories and datetime axis in the same time.